# Program gets "Expression: string subscript out of range"

Tags: c++, windows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Latin(string words)
{

string strWord, strSentence = "";
int length = 0, index = 0;
while (words[index] != '\0')
{
    if(words.find(' ', index) != -1)
    {
        length = words.find(' ', index);
        length -= index;
        strWord = words.substr(index,length);
        strWord.insert(length, "ay");
        strWord.insert(length, 1, words[index]);
        strWord.erase(0,1);
        index += length +1;
    }
    else
    {
        strWord = words.substr(index);
        length = strWord.length();
        strWord.insert(length, "ay");
        strWord.insert(length,1,words[index]);
        strWord.erase(0,1);
        index = words.length();
    }

    strSentence += (strWord + " ");
}

return strSentence;
}

int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin,str);
    str = Latin(str);
    cout<<str<<endl;


return 0;
}
```

I get this error that says [image: http://imgur.com/OI0TgBG]

I have no clue what to do. As I am new to this, this is a program that is suppose to ask for user input of a length of words and translate them into pig Latin. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should step through your code with the debugger and find out where it throws the exception.  That will help you figure out what is wrong.

Comment: click "Retry" then see the call stack on the debugger

Comment: @erip: actually, `std::string`s _are_ null terminated! See 21.4.5 [string.access] paragraphs 1 and 2 which essentially state that `s.[s.size()] == cT()` for `s` being of type `std::basic_string<cT>`.

Comment: Note that `find()` return `std::string::npos` when it fails to find a suitable location. There is no guarantee that `npos` has the value `-1`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Actually npos is declared as `static const size_type npos = -1;` in 21.4(5) [basic.string]

Comment: @NathanOliver: thanks! I should actually check my assertions, too...!

Comment: [Apparently OP's code is OK](https://ideone.com/UPZJXX). Just compile with `-std=c++11` and you're good.

Comment: @DietmarKühl that was added in C++11, whereas OP's screenshot indicates use of a compiler from 2010

Comment: @M.M: when I commented, the screenshot wasn't there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I really wanted to make my own life difficult, I'd do this quite a bit differently. First, I'd use a `std::stringstream` to break the input string into words to process. Then, I'd use `std::rotate` to move the first character of the string to the end. Finally, I'd wrap that all in `std::transform` to manage applying the function to each word in succession.

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::stringstream buffer(line);
std::stringstream result;

std::transform(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(buffer),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(result, " "),
    [](std::string s) { 
        std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1, s.end()); 
        s += "ay"; 
        return s; 
    });
```

Of course, this doesn't know the special rules for things like words that start with vowels or letter pairs like `sh` or `ch`, but it looks like that's outside the scope of the task at hand.

For more on `std::rotate`, I recommend watching some of Sean Parent's videos.